# When Passing checkbox values as JSON in Jquery, I get an error: 500 Internal Server

Tags: json, model-view-controller

I want to pass a checkbox value with JSON, but when debugging my code I get this error:

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:2020/LabAccess/LabAccesscheck"
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'
```

What's the problem? I use this code in view and control.

```
$(function () {
     $("#GetAccess").change(function () {
         alert('asa')
         var newValue = true;//$(this).checkbox;
         var itemID = '2' ;
         alert('ii')
         $.ajax({
             type: "post",
             url: "/LabAccess/LabAccesscheck",
             data: { itemID: '67' },
             datatype: "json",
             traditional: true,
             success: function (Data) {
                 //alert(data.itemID);
                 //alert(data.itemID);
             },
             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

             }
         });

   });
 });
   [HttpPost]
        public virtual JsonResult LabAccesscheck(string itemID)
        {

            //Int16 ID = Convert.ToInt16(TempData["id"].ToString());
            TempData["fulname"] = _UserService.getfullname(36);

            string type = string.Empty;
            IList<P_User_Get_Lab_Access_List_Result> selected = _ILabAccess.GetDataTablebyUser(36, "Userid");
            //return (PartialView(MVC.BaseAdmin.LabAccess.Views._ListbyUser, selected));

            return Json(PartialView(MVC.BaseAdmin.LabAccess.Views._ListbyUser, selected),   JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: check if you have more than one calsses having same name?!!

Comment: and how you getting model? in code??